# Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Tags: port, remote-access, gcloud

I have created vm instance in gcloud. And setup firewall rule to allow connection from port 5000.I added network tag to my vm instance.

But if i test the connection by teneting to port 5000 I get

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Content of **netstat -lnp**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

From your `netstat` output there is nothing listening on the port 5000 so connection is refused.

Comment: I am using ubuntu-server 16.04.
I tried **sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT**
With No luck

Comment: I tried **sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
** with no luck. The content of netstat still not showing port 5000 listening.
I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Any Idea how to resolve this?